# Как сделать такой скрипт на своем сайте?

Tags: php

Требуется показывать определенного пользователя лишь введя определенный адрес www, как в случае с ВК vk.com/idxxxx, в базе данных на данный момент лишь есть несколько полей, id, 
имя, логин и пароль. Форма для пользователя уже создана, как теперь загрузить информацию из бд при переходе через строку браузера? Например www.мойсайт.ru/id5

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Как это реализовать? Какими средствами?